# How to suspend bash within bash

Tags: bash, keyboard-shortcuts, shell, process

Is it possible to suspend a bash that was invoked by another bash? For example, if I use `su` to become a different user but want to switch back to my own user for a moment.  For another example, in an SSH session, I can use the ~ shortcut (~, ^Z) to suspend the remote shell and return to my local shell (but that's obviously an SSH feature, not the shell).

bash intercepts ^Z to do its own process control, so it must be a separate command (if it's even supported).  But trying to find it only results in information about the normal process control.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bash has a `suspend` builtin:

```
suspend: suspend [-f]
    Suspend shell execution.

    Suspend the execution of this shell until it receives a SIGCONT signal.
    Unless forced, login shells cannot be suspended.

    Options:
      -f    force the suspend, even if the shell is a login shell

    Exit Status:
    Returns success unless job control is not enabled or an error occurs.
```

Comment: Ahha! That's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 5):

Try with:

```
kill -STOP $$
```

where `$$` is the `PID` of the current shell.

You can bind it to <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>z</kbd> for example by adding to `~/.inputrc`:

```
"\ez": "kill -STOP $$\n"
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you! Never knew about .inputrc

Comment: It controls the way `bash` reads/edit the user input, see `man readline`, it can be very useful, it's worth to mention the commands: `history-search-backward` and `history-search-backward`.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you were asking for, but I normally use [screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html) when I'm doing things like that.  However, screen is not installed by default on all systems.

Comment: I actually work in screen all the time. I run screen on my local machine and have SSH sessions into a bunch of others.  So I don't typically run screen on the remote systems because screen-within-screen is clumsy.  And I'm too lazy to open another session :-).  I'm used to hitting ^Z in vim to suspend it when I need to run some commands (I know vim has ! but it's not the same as a shell).